# Method invocation 'fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { @Override public void on...' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I create new Blank Activity project in Android Studio 1.5.1 with min API 15

[image]

and after generated code i have this warning/error:

[on pasteBin](http://pastebin.com/6VjurL2B)

[image]

Code in [MainActivity.java](http://pastebin.com/gmcU05Jr):

```
package com.gamecodeschool.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Code in [content_my.xml](http://pastebin.com/k5yq2Fsq):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.gamecodeschool.myapplication.MyActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/my_layout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code in [my_layout.xml](http://pastebin.com/WN7eWtju):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.gamecodeschool.myapplication.MyActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_my" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Tell me please how to fix this problem and why it happens. I'm new in Android and Android Studio. Previously I used the Apache Cordova.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just check/assert whether fab is null:

```
if (fab != null)
```

or:

```
assert fab != null;
```

Like this:

```
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    if (fab != null)
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
                 Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                 .setAction("Action", null).show();
           }
     });
```

Comment: Hi Nonthonbam, It is a warning. And the warning is in the `setAction` method of SnackBar. if view (in this case `fab`) is null, it will not show a warning.

Comment: This warning will appear for all views, not only for snackbar

Comment: In this case `fab` is initialized, so this warning will not show. the warning is shown in this case because the null value passed to the setAction method

Comment: What about other views? How can we avoid this?

Comment: If the view is properly initialized this warning will not show. but if the view is null it may throw `NullPointerException` at runtime

Comment: For me it is very strange that in Android Studio there are errors with default generated code

Comment: Now we need to check for nulls for all views, previously it wasn't necessary

Comment: we need to add null check in lot of places, that's not the case here.

Comment: @Boss but nevertheless I had to do it ?

Comment: I have changed the code just like you have suggested but it still shows the warning

Comment: Can you show some code how you achieved that? For me the warning goes away only if I do a null check.

Comment: I have added an answer, please check below

Comment: @Boss I added a check as suggested by Nonthonbam and warning disappeared

Comment: The warning does not go away.

Comment: With the latest AS and sdk I think that this newly introduced null check is a must to remove the warning

Comment: @NonthonbamTonthoi I use Java SE Development Kit 7 as recommended on android studio website

Comment: @Mikhail So is your problem fixed now

Comment: @NonthonbamTonthoi but my problem is solved with your answer. why you got downvote ?

Answer (score 3):

```
Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
```

In this line pass your `onClicklistener` instance as the second parameter to the `setAction` method.

> Snackbars can contain an action which is set via
>   setAction(CharSequence, android.view.View.OnClickListener).

Change it like this

```
    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        .setAction("Action", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //whatever you want to do when "Action" is clicked in the SnackBar
            }
        }).show();
```

Comment: I'm having the same issues, even this I'm added an action to the Snackbar it's still giving me this warning. the solution is to create the View.OnclickListener outside the onCreate and pass it into the snackBar , for some reason it's work.

Answer (score 0):

This null pointer is coming due to Snackbar not because of your floating button. You need to create the object of click listener in set Action method instead of passing null.